# Haskell do-block return error

Tags: haskell

I have a simple function:

```
func :: Int
func = do
  x <- 1
  return x
```

But I got an error message as follows:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘m0 b0’ with ‘Int’
```

What's wrong with my function?

Comment: The right side of `<-` has to have a monad type, and `1` is just a bare `Int`, not something in a monad.  `do` is only something you use with monads, and you're not doing anything monadic here.

Comment: Are you aware that what you probably want can simply be written as `func = 1`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's just for a demo

Comment: `func = do  x <- return 1; return x`

Comment: @JaredSimpson, your proposed "solution" has errors: 

**1.** It doesn't type-check, since `func` is of type `:: Int`, note that `Int` is not in a monad. 

**2.** If it were in a monad, it just doesn't make sense to take the `1` out of the monad to just re-insert it with another return, we would do `func = return 1`.

Comment: Have you tried one of the fine Haskell tutorials available? I'd recommend starting with that; these kinds of questions are not ideal for SO.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The right side of `<-` must have the type `m a` where `a` is an arbitrary type (that then becomes the type of the left side) and `m` is the monad that the do-block belongs to. In your case the type of the right side is `1`, which does not have that type.

   If all you want to do is to bind a value to `x`, you need to use `let x = 1`, not `<-`.
2. The type of `return` is `Monad m => a -> m a`, so if we take the type of `x` to be `Int`, the type of `return x` is `Monad m => m Int`. But according to your type signature, you just want the type to be `Int`, not `m Int`. Therefore you shouldn't use `return` (or `do`-notation for that matter).

The correct way to write the definition that you're trying to write would be:

```
f = 1
```

or if you want to have a local `x`

```
f =
  let x = 1 in
  x
```

or

```
f = x
  where x = 1
```